# Twilio voice API - Send recorded message when voicemail is reached

Tags: c#, asp.net, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I am using below code to place a call from agent(Web Browser interface) to customer(phone).

```
var response = new VoiceResponse();
var dial = new Dial(callerId: callerId,action : "https://ba2d9819.ngrok.io/voice/CallEnd");
if (Regex.IsMatch(to, "^[\\d\\+\\-\\(\\) ]+$"))
{
    dial.Number(to);
}
else
{
    dial.Client(to);
}

response.Dial(dial);
```

This works fine when customer picks up the call. I have a requirement to play a prerecorded audio message when customer do not pickup the call and it goes to voicemail. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using this?  https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/answering-machine-detection

Comment: i did. but i am not sure how can do chaining of call and playing audio when voicemail is detected.